# convert all files in specific directory to xml (batch)

Tags: xml, batch-file, powershell

I want to convert all pcap files from a specific directory into xml in the same directory.

e.g:

- aaa.pcap -> aaa.xml
- bbb.pcap -> bbb.xml

I want to do that with:

```
tshark -r aaa.pcap -T psml > bbb.xml
```

And if I execute the batch file again, it should only convert the new pcap files. e.g.

- NOT aaa.pcap -> aaa.xml
- only ccc.pcap -> ccc.xml

Can somebody help me to do that? 
Alternative: Powershell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following one liner will work on the command line, without any batch file.

```
for %F in (*.pcap) do if not exist "%~dpnF.xml" tshark -r "%F" -T psml >"%~dpnF.xml"
```

If you want to put the command in a batch file, then you must double up the percents

```
for %%F in (*.pcap) do if not exist "%%~dpnF.xml" tshark -r "%%F" -T psml >"%%~dpnF.xml"
```

You can include path information in the IN() clause if you want to convert files that are not in the current directory.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Get-ChildItem *.pcap | Where {!(Test-Path "$($_.BaseName).xml")} | 
    Foreach {tshark -r $_.FullName -T psml > "$($_.BaseName).xml"}
```

Or the short-hand version:

```
ls *.pcap | ?{!(Test-Path "$($_.BaseName).xml")} | %{tshark -r $_.FullName -T psml > "$($_.BaseName).xml"}
```